# Sum up over np.array or np.float

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, types

We have a numpy-based algorithm that is supposed to handle data of different type.

```
def my_fancy_algo(a):
    b = np.sum(a, axis=1)
    # Do something b
    return b
```

If we pass `a=np.array[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]` then `b` evaluates to `[6.0]`.

If we pass `a=6.0` then we get

```
*** ValueError: 'axis' entry is out of bounds
```

The desired behavior would be that we get same return value `6.0` not (`[6.0]`)  for both inputs.

What is the correct pythonic and safe way to handle this? `type`? `shape`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your example array actually gives the same problem as a scalar:

```
>>> a = np.array([1.0,2.0,3.0])
>>> np.sum(a, axis=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 1724, in sum
    out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 32, in _sum
    return umr_sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
ValueError: 'axis' entry is out of bounds
```

The good news is that there's a numpy function exactly for ensuring making numpy calls with `axis=1` will work - it's called [`np.atleast_2d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.atleast_2d.html):

```
>>> np.sum(np.atleast_2d(a), axis=1)
array([ 6.])
>>> np.sum(np.atleast_2d(6.0), axis=1)
array([ 6.])
```

But since you apparently want a scalar answer, you could instead just drop the `axis` argument entirely:

```
>>> np.sum(a)
6.0
>>> np.sum(6.0)
6.0
```

Answer (score 3):

`np.sum(np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0]), axis=1)` produces `ValueError: 'axis' entry is out of bounds` for me.

Did you mean to put `axis=0` in line 2? Then it works for arrays as well as scalars:

```
>>> np.sum(np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0]), axis=0)
6
>>> np.sum(3, axis=0)
3
```